# Scroll through a text input and list of <li> items with keyboard up/down keys without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'd like to scroll through this list from the search box down the list using the up and down arrow keys. I'm using ReactJS and using React Hotkeys to handle the event listeners, but I'm not sure what the best way to actually handle the iterating over the list is.

I'd like to avoid using tabIndex because I'd like for the list and the search box as a whole to have only one tabIndex for the whole element. What would be the best way to accomplish this? ES6 preferred, but any solution will do. I don't know how to approach this.

Any advice you can offer would be very appreciated! Thanks for your time.

[image: A list of <li> items to scroll through]

Comment: Are you trying to create a searchable dropdown?

Comment: It's more of a searchable list since there's no animation, but same idea, yes.

I'd like to use the arrow keys to navigate down from the search into the list and visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone else will write up a longer, more exact answer but here's a short answer that will hopefully help you solve it -

You could keep track of a `selected` (number) value on the component's `state` that you increment/decrement when the up/down arrow keys are pressed.

The state update will trigger the component to re-render, and you can apply the `selected` class on the item whose index matches your `selectedIndex`